# Monitor Battery level on android phone

Tags: android, performance, intentfilter, batterymanager

How can I programatically monitor the battery level on my android device ? I have read the examples posted on stackoverflow and the `BatteryManager` documentation where we need to register the Receiver for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`. My question is that I need to continuosly monitor the Battery level . When I use `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` intent the update stays at a constant value till I exit and re-launch my app. Is there a way to monitor the battery level for the entire duration that my app is running?

Comment: have you used EXTRA_LEVEL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to use following code, if you run it, you get different information for of the battery. There are also a lot more infos you can get, but therefore you should just pic the right commands in the android api for the battery.

```
    public void getActualData(){

    IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Intent batteryStatus = this.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

    //are we charging / charged?
    int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

    if(isCharging == true){
        tvCharged.setText("CHARGING");
    }else{
        tvCharged.setText("NOT CHARGING");
    }

    //how are we charging
    int chargePlug = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

    if(usbCharge == true){
        tvHowCharging.setText("USB");
    }else{
        tvHowCharging.setText("ELECTRICAL OUTLET");
    }

    //get battery level and print it out
    int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    tvLevelOutput.setText(level + " / 100");
    pbLevel.setProgress(level);
    pbLevel.invalidate();

    //get battery temperatur
    int temp = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1);
    tvTempOutput.setText(temp + "Grad");
    pbTemp.incrementProgressBy(temp);
    pbTemp.invalidate();

    //get battery voltage
    int voltage = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);
    tvVoltageOutput.setText(voltage + " V");
    pbVoltage.incrementProgressBy(voltage);
    pbVoltage.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: did it solve your problem? then don't forget to mark as solved